# Travel Voucher and refundable tickets

Tags: refunds, vouchers

I understand that airlines only provide travel vouchers to be used in the future for travel changes due to COVID (e.g. you cannot travel because you are positive). But, let's say that credit is used to buy a refundable ticket, and that ticket is then cancelled for a refund, will the airlines refund the money or simply give back the airline credit?

Comment: It’s unlikely they would refund cash if you paid with a voucher, but in some cases they will end up refunding cash if you weren’t able to use your voucher for a given time. However this varies a LOT on the country (of the airline and where you live, fly from and/or fly to), the airline, the fare, when you bought the ticket, when you were supposed to fly originally, and so on, that it’s nearly impossible to give a generic answer…

Comment: @jcaron Can you please provide some examples/sources when they might end up refunding cash?

Comment: There is no such thing as "airlines". There are lot of different airlines with their own terms & conditions and contract of carriage which spells this out in great detail. I don't think there is "general" answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy an airline ticket, you should check the fare conditions. Usually it is a wall of text written in a language noone can understand, that would boil down to something like "refund is available to the original form of payment" for refundable fares. Which means that if you paid with a voucher - you'll get a refund with a voucher.